# Add an Extra Shopping Cart Price Rule

Tags: cart, price

We would like to add a Shopping Cart Rule whereby the customer adds a coupon/voucher code to the checkout page.
And this would remove the TAX from selected products, these products would be Tax free.
I have worked out that I can apply a % discount, to the including tax price etc, but that does not make the product Tax Free, just cheaper.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If memory serves me correct, if you want a product to be tax free, you will need to set the "Tax Class" on the product to "None". This can be found in the Product -> Prices tab.

If you want to apply this to certain customers, you could use something like Enterprise's customer segments module which hooks quite nicely into The promotions engine.

Comment: Thank you Shaughn, I will look into that module. Ultimately we want it so that if a customer fills in a Tax declaration form, they get a voucher code - if they enter this code in the cart, then they dont pay tax on certain products.

Comment: Hi Shaughn, we are using CE version 1.9.1.0 so dont have the Enterprise options. Any other ideas on how to make a product Tax free if a coupon entered, rather than just cheaper?